# Remove the Exipre header in Linux apache server

Tags: apache

I am getting Expire Header as **Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT** on my webpage  how i can remove expire header using apache.

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Answer (score 0):

In your .htacess:

```
ExpiresActive Off
```

It is not good to disable this complete.

Also take a look at [`mod_expires`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html).

> This module controls the setting of the Expires HTTP header and the
>   max-age directive of the Cache-Control HTTP header in server
>   responses. The expiration date can set to be relative to either the
>   time the source file was last modified, or to the time of the client
>   access.
>
> These HTTP headers are an instruction to the client about the
>   document's validity and persistence. If cached, the document may be
>   fetched from the cache rather than from the source until this time has
>   passed. After that, the cache copy is considered "expired" and
>   invalid, and a new copy must be obtained from the source.
>
> To modify Cache-Control directives other than max-age (see RFC 2616
>   section 14.9), you can use the Header directive.
>
> When the Expires header is already part of the response generated by
>   the server, for example when generated by a CGI script or proxied from
>   an origin server, this module does not change or add an Expires or
>   Cache-Control header.

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month 15 days 2 hours"
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 5 hours 3 minutes"
```

Comment: Hi, I had added the ExpiresActive Off and also added the EpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 days" , but still i am getting below lines as header  Cache-Control public
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 44412
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date Sat, 08 Nov 2014 12:46:22 GMT
Etag cf64df2f5fe34548b38760b1c58ac353
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma public